# Retrieve XML Variable in XSL file and say YES if found

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have problems with the Xpath expression test="$roles/roles/role='HOBSCS1GB'" . Can anyone help in solving. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"> 

  <xsl:template match="/"> 

    <xsl:variable name="roles"> 
  <roles> 
    <role>HOBSCS1ROI</role> 
    <role>HOBSCS1GB</role> 
    <role>HOBSCS1FT</role> 
  </roles> 
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:if test="$roles/roles/role='HOBSCS1GB'">
      <xsl:value-of select="'YES'"/>
    </xsl:if> 

  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you have problems with something, it's a good idea to say what the problems are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to find if a the `roles` element has one or more role elements with text = 'HOBSCS1GB': (Works in Saxon)

```
<xsl:if test="$roles/roles[role='HOBSCS1GB']">
  <xsl:value-of select="'YES'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Note that certain parsers like Microsoft may require you to tell the parser that `$roles` is a result tree fragment, by using `node-set()`, like so: (Works in msxsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" ... />

<xsl:if test="msxsl:node-set($roles)/roles[role='HOBSCS1GB']">
  <xsl:value-of select="'YES'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Or in xsltproc:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" ... />

<xsl:if test="exsl:node-set($roles)/roles[role='HOBSCS1GB']">
  <xsl:value-of select="'YES'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: very good. I'll need to do this transform through Tomcat but your answer explains it very clearly. Much appreciated